# validate input each time the user add or remove character datatable primefaces

Tags: validation, primefaces, datatable, onkeyup

I have this column in my datatable and I want to validate it each time the user add or remove one character in the input 
I tested that :

```
<p:column headerText="Quantité" style="width:20%">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{arti.qte}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:inputText 
                                    value="#{arti.qte}"   >
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener= "#{mvmtdepotMB.keyupQte}" />
                                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.1" maximum="#{arti.qtemax}"  />
                                </p:inputText>
                                <p:message  for="qdf" />
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
```

but the keyup method is not invoked and the validation does not

how can I achieve that

Answer (score 2):

You should detect the keyup event inside of the `p:inputText`:

```
<p:inputText value="#{arti.qte}" onkeyup="validate()"/>
```

And this is going to execute a `p:remoteCommand`:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="validate" actionListener="#{mvmtdepotMB.keyupQte}"/>
```

Put `p:remoteCommand` outside of the `p:dataTable`.

If you want to pass parameters to `p:remoteCommand`:

```
onkeyup="validate([{name: 'name1', value: 'value1'}, {name: 'name2', value: 'value2'}]);"
```

And `p:remoteCommand` actionListener can retrieve these via:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String name1 = (String) map.get("name1");
String name2 = (String) map.get("name2");
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I have one  #{arti.qtemax} associated to each row of datatable

Comment: @simonTifo check it out again.

Comment: @simonTifo you can check an answer even 1 year later but do not forget this creates a bad impression about you.

Comment: thank you @Ömer Faruk Almalı for your advice, you are right, I tested your suggestion : `<p:remoteCommand name="validate" >
       <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.01"  />
      </p:remoteCommand>`  but I show this error : `<f:validateDoubleRange> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.remotecommand.RemoteCommand@13fc6cc`

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and/or upvote. Also do not insist via `f:validateDoubleRange` because parent is a remoteCommand if you need to pass a value you can also use `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.value}"                                                               value="#{value}"/>`